# Complex Ordering In Django with respect to related models

Tags: python, django

Here are what my models currently look like:

```
class Message(TimeStampedModel):
"""
A single exchange between two users. A set of messages related to a specific ticket constitutes a conversation
"""

conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation,
                                 blank=False,
                                 null=False,
                                 related_name='message',
                                 )

body = models.TextField(max_length=message_model_settings.get('BODY_MAX_LENGTH'))

is_read = models.BooleanField(blank=False,
                              null=False,
                              default=False)

datetime_read = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,
                                     null=True,
                                     default=None)


class Conversation(TimeStampedModel):
"""
Just a collection of messages between two users for a particular ticket
"""

sender = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           blank=False,
                           null=False,
                           related_name='sender',
                           )

receiver = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             blank=False,
                             null=False,
                             related_name='receiver',
                             )

ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket,
                           blank=False,
                           null=False
                           )
```

I need to return a QuerySet of conversations that all belong to a single user, which are sorted in descending order where the key is the earliest message creation_date (defined in TimeStampModel) in the set of all messages for each particular conversation object.

So I need to grab one conversation for a given user, then grab all of its associated messages, find which message has the most recent creation date, and then do that for every conversation for that user so that I can use the creation date to sort the conversations.

I've been looking at using managers the moment, but I'm honestly not sure that's the best way.  I also noticed an option called "order_with_respect_to." Could I order conversations with respect to the message creation date this way? Worst case scenario I'm going to need to write raw SQL, but I'd like to avoid that since I'm not great at it.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way easier than that. You can use annotations to get the minimum creation date, then order on the annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Q

conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(receiver=user)) \
                                    .annotate(min_date=Min('message__creation_date')) \
                                    .order_by('-min_date')
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I read the entire section on aggregation and annotations. I didn't know this was possible. Thank you!